# Concat blocks of rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How does one concatenate strings that appear in blocks of rows using arrayformula?

[Example spreadsheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZWr6GUMDrV-ONro_YxgzOPBSpAXpmFTpYua6S_jywSU/edit?usp=sharing)

The string data is in column A. Each block of 5 rows needs to be concatenated into a single cell string and the results listed in column B.

```
    | Row | Column A   |
    |1 Hd |  -Header-  |
    |2    |1 This is   |
    |3    |the         |
    |4    |            |
    |5    |first row   |
    |6    |            |
    |7    |2 This is   |
    |8    |the         |
    |9    |            |
    |10   |second row  |
    |11   |            |
    |12   |3 This is   |
    |13   |the         |
    ...
```

In column B I want to see:

```
    1 This is the first row
    2 This is the second row
    3 This is the third row
    4 This is the fourth row
```

What I get is:

```
    1 This is the first row
    1 This is the first row
    1 This is the first row
    1 This is the first row
```

My formula below (in cell B1) nearly works:

```
=query({ArrayFormula(if(mod(row(A:A)+2,5)=1,if(A2:A<>"",trim(join(" ",indirect("A"&row()&":A"&row()+4))),),))},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)
```

(the +2 and A2 references just step over the header row)

What I expected was that arrayformula would step through the rows and pass the current iteration row number to the formula. Apparently not.  Can my formula be fixed or do I need to address the problem in a completely different way?  I'll be happy to hear all opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DQlJX0A8pbOl_cdylE-Fk53EVAQ3og5Ig-dolwH2ij8/edit?usp=sharing) of your sheet.  In it you'll find this formula which should work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(MID(QUERY({TEXT(ROW(A2:A21),"000")&A2:A21,INT((ROW(A2:A21)-2)/5)},"select MAX(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"),4,100),,9^9))))
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer as preferred even though it is more complex than @player0 elegant and readable option. I had to slightly modify it to apply it to my real data length and It seems to traverse the many rows more efficiently. I suspect, but have not tested, that this may be due to it having only a single call per iteration to the burdensome QUERY as opposed to 5 calls to the slightly lighter weight FILTER function.  It might be useful to other readers if anyone could add real knowledge to this.  Appreciated both answers.

Comment: @DeeKay789 I will add some explanatory notes in the sheet, but I also want to ask why you referred to QUERY() as "burdensome" but FILTER() as "relatively lighter weight"?  that has not been my experience.  The way I solved this is using a method I got from the other user actually  (player0, who knows where he got it!?) 
Basically it involves taking advantage of a trick that the QUERY() function can use to "smush" any number of header rows into a single row.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(
 FILTER(A2:A, MOD(ROW(A2:A)-2, 5)=0)&" "&
 FILTER(A2:A, MOD(ROW(A2:A)-3, 5)=0)&" "&
 FILTER(A2:A, MOD(ROW(A2:A)-4, 5)=0)&" "&
 FILTER(A2:A, MOD(ROW(A2:A)-5, 5)=0)&" "&
 FILTER(A2:A, MOD(ROW(A2:A)-6, 5)=0)))
```

[image]